# why cannot filter records with ~ symbol in excel

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I have a list of record and I want to filter out those records that contain "~6". The problem is....
I can only filter if it is "~(space)6" but not "~6". When I try to filter "~6", I get the same list of result as when I filter  the results which contain 6. I have been trying for whole day and has no idea what is wrong. Anyone can help? Thank a lot. 
Here is example data :

- ~6
- jhjh ~3
- dfdf~6
- dfdfd6dfdfd
- fgfg~6 fdfdd

Here is the result I want if I filter the records that contain ~6

- ~6
- dfdf~6
- fgfg~6 fdfdd

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using a double tilde as the filter text, i.e., ~~6. (The tilde is the escape character for wildcard searches.)

Comment: wow. Thank you so much! I was stuck with it for whole day. Thank a lot.

Comment: can I know what ~ stand for in excel that it cannot work? What is wildcard search?

Comment: When you want to do a find or search (or a filter) in Excel, you can use a "?" to stand in for any character or a "*" to stand for any set of characters. For example, "pi?" will match "pit" and "pin". To actually match on the "?" character, you use the tilde to let Excel know you don't want to use ? as a so-called wildcard character: so "pi~?" will match "pi?" but not "pin". Because "~" is used in this special way, you need to use "~~" to let Excel know you actually want to match the tilde. See [this link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/wildcard-characters-HP005203612.aspx) also.